# WSO2 IS Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 IS 5.10 with docker and after making a change to the image, which has nothing to do with JSPs, opening the dashboard on the service provider list I see a white screen.
In wso2 log I found errors like this:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [bridgeservlet] threw exception org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: [17] in the generated java file: [/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.10.0/lib/tomcat/work/Catalina/localhost/ROOT/proxytemp/hc_1893914628/org/apache/jsp/application/list_002dservice_002dproviders_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.common.model.xsd.ApplicationBasicInfo resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [118] in the jsp file: [/application/list-service-providers.jsp]
ApplicationBasicInfo cannot be resolved to a type
115:             <%
116:                 String BUNDLE = "org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.mgt.ui.i18n.Resources";
117:                 ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(BUNDLE, request.getLocale());
118:                 ApplicationBasicInfo[] applications = null;
119:
120:                 String filterString = request.getParameter(ApplicationMgtUIConstants.SP_NAME_FILTER);
121:                 filterString = ApplicationMgtUIUtil.resolveFilterString(filterString);
```

this disappears when restarting the image.
I’d like to know what it’s due to

Comment: There is a similar issue reported https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/7702

Comment: thanks, it’s my same problem

Comment: Any updates on a solution for this issue?